# Zurb foundation can't focus input field inside modal

Tags: html, input, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to set the focus of an input field inside my form when I reveal a modal using ZURB Foundation framework. I am really truly sorry if this question has been asked before I've been having problems finding a solution to this for a while.

This is what I have:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   <form action="php_scripts/post_message.php" method="POST" name="modalForm" id="modalForm">
      <label for="curse">Пиши си овде:</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="curse" id="curse" placeholder="Напиши што ти душа сака.." required="true"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button secondary tiny right" value="OK">
   </form>
   <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Everytime I click a button this modal pops up and I want my input field (textarea) to be in focus when I do that. I tried adding the `autofocus` attribute and I also tried using javascript to set the focus when I click the button or when this div shows or loads (onshow and onload methods). Nothing seems to work for me so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll have to use JS or jQuery to handle the opened event like this..

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/Ahs4oZDsWn

Comment: Thanks a LOT I checked the demo and it works fine but since I'm working mostly with Javascript and not Jquery I don't quite understand the code is it possible that you give me non-Jquery solution? If not I'll just use this thank you :)

Comment: AFAIK js is the only way

Comment: yes ok I made it all work, thank you again. I will check that jquery out as I see I need to learn it. : ]

Answer (score 1):

With Foundation 6 the event name has changed:

```
$(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    console.log('asdfasdfsadf')
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```